# Why is anime.js not working on my computer?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't know why anime.js doesn't work on my computer. I have added the CDN in my HTML file, but it still won't work, why?

```js
"use strict";

anime({
    targets: '#ball',
    translateX: 250
  });
```

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    height: 100vh;
}

#ball{
    border: black solid medium;
    background-color: cyan;
    width: 2%;
    height: 2%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="ball"></div>

  </body>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
  <script> src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.js"</script>
</html>
```

Comment: The src of the second <script> element needs to be inside the angle brackets

Comment: You're including your script before the anime script, and the brackets are wrong on the second script as the syntax highlighting shows. Replace those two lines with `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.js"></script><script src="test.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

Like @ggorlen and I said, your brackets for the second script tag were incorrect.

```js
"use strict";

anime({
    targets: '#ball',
    translateX: 250
  });
```

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    height: 100vh;
}

#ball{
    border: black solid medium;
    background-color: cyan;
    width: 2%;
    height: 2%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="ball"></div>

  </body>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: This answer results in error if you run the snippet.

Comment: @LawrenceJohnson It's not an error with anime.js being missing though. That's what the question was about.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="ball"></div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.js"></script>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Your syntax for the `script` tag to the `anime.js` file was incorrect, and your `test.js` needs to be referenced after it in order for the `anime()` function to be defined.

Answer (score -2):

Add this link in your code https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js

```js
  var animation = anime({
    targets: '#ball',
    translateX: 250
  });
  var animation = anime.js;
  var anime = animation;
  var animation = anime.js;
  var ball = anime.js;
  var animation = anime.js;
  var anime = animation;
  var anime = anime.js;
  var anime = animation;
  var animation = animation;
  var anime = animation;
  var animation = animation;
  var animation = anime.js;
  var anime = anime.js;
  var animaton = anime.js;
  var anime = animation;
  var anime = anime.js;
```

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    height: 100vh;
}

#ball{
    border: black solid medium;
    background-color: cyan;
    width: 2%;
    height: 2%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="ball"></div>

  </body>
  </html>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
<script>https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js</script>
```

Comment: Can I know what was wrong in my answer.

Comment: apart from formatting problems, this does not really answer the question, you can see that the author already has included this script